# d3 v4 geo draws boundary inverted

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geo

When I draw the Bermuda Triangle in an SVG element the scale is not what I expect (triangle should extend to edges of box) and the fill is backward (instead of drawing a triangle, it draws a square with a triangle cut out).

```js
var geojson = {
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Bermuda Triangle",
        "area": 1150180
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-64.73, 32.31],
            [-80.19, 25.76],
            [-66.09, 18.43],
            [-64.73, 32.31]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "type":"FeatureCollection"
};

var width = 480;
var height = 480;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("style", "border: 2px solid black");

var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], geojson);
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(geojson.features)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("stroke-width", "1")
  .style("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's change this:

```
[
    [-64.73, 32.31],
    [-80.19, 25.76],
    [-66.09, 18.43],
    [-64.73, 32.31]
]
```

To this:

```
[
    [-64.73, 32.31],
    [-66.09, 18.43],
    [-80.19, 25.76],
    [-64.73, 32.31]
]
```

It seems like a small change, but it is an important one: D3 expects the polygon vertices in a **clockwise** order.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo):

> Spherical polygons also require a winding order convention to determine which side of the polygon is the inside: the exterior ring for polygons smaller than a hemisphere must be **clockwise**, while the exterior ring for polygons larger than a hemisphere must be anticlockwise. (emphasis mine)

Also, this is an interesting bl.ocks made by Bostock (D3 creator), didactically explaining your issue: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a7bdfeb041e850799a8d3dce4d8c50c8

Here is your code with that change (and removing the `fitSize`):

```js
var geojson = {
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Bermuda Triangle",
      "area": 1150180
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-64.73, 32.31],
          [-66.09, 18.43],
          [-80.19, 25.76],
          [-64.73, 32.31]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
};

var width = 480;
var height = 480;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("style", "border: 2px solid black");

var projection = d3.geoMercator();
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(geojson.features)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("stroke-width", "1")
  .style("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thought I might add, d3 is relatively unique in this regard. If you fail to follow the right hand rule in leaflet, openlayers, or qgis etc there is no consequence. Most tools don't care, and some tools even give geojson that doesn't use the right hand rule (turf) - even validators do not anticipate the inverted polygon situation. D3's implemetnation is unique in implementing geojson standard as specified, this answer is only possible because d3 uses a spherical geometry for geojson, and this is why d3 is great for making maps. Any other library this doesnt matter, great answer.

Answer (score 6):

If someone will see a similar problem, I created a tool which will help you to rewind or reverse geojson

It helped me to make changes in some geoJson files, without much hassle

https://observablehq.com/@bumbeishvili/rewind-geojson

You can run it as a snippet just bellow

```html
<div class="notebook-content">
  
</div>

<script type="module"> 

import notebook from "https://api.observablehq.com/@bumbeishvili/rewind-geojson.js";  //  "download code" url

document.querySelector('.notebook-content').innerHTML =notebook.modules[0].variables
.filter(d=>d)
.map((d,i)=>` <div class=" observable-wrapper div-number-${i}"></div>`)
.join('')
.concat('<div style="display:none" class="hidden"></div>')


import {Inspector, Runtime} from "https://unpkg.com/@observablehq/runtime@3/dist/runtime.js"; 
let i=1;
Runtime.load(notebook, (variable) => { 
if(i==4 ){i++;  return new Inspector(document.querySelector(`.hidden`));}
if(i==13)return;
return new Inspector(document.querySelector(`.observable-wrapper:nth-child(${i++})`));
 }); 


</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much for sharing this link!!! Its has saved me a lot of pain! I wish I could upvote you more than once!

Comment: Amazing tool, saved me from hours of pain!