# d3 geopath, geojsonlint, CW vs CCW

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

So this is probably going to be a stupid question and I am missing something obvious, but I've hit a bit of confusion and I'm hoping someone can tell me where I am going wrong.

According to the d3 docs:

> Important: the inside of a polygon is all points that the polygon winds around in a clockwise order. If your GeoJSON input has polygons in the wrong winding order, you must reverse them.

Ok, simple enough.  However, for every GeoJSON file I've been trying from my project, which lint (via https://geojsonlint.com/) fine, are coming out inverted when trying to display them using d3's geopaths.

So I go to the [d3indepth](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/c6df643a689ce9278b3341f87b6fcf04) example, which has a nice small GeoJSON example included in it.  The example works, and the example data works in my own code.  But when I take that example data and run it through the linter, it fails with 'Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule', and my own 'make sure this is correct' code identifies the polygons as counterclockwise.

Now, the example does seem to match what is listed in RFC7946

> A linear ring MUST follow the right-hand rule with respect to the
> area it bounds, i.e., exterior rings are counterclockwise, and
> holes are clockwise.

So that matches the behavior I see in d3, but not the documentation, and seems at odd with GeoJSONLint.

In trying to figure this out I ran into this earlier question:

[d3 v4 geo draws boundary inverted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234805/d3-v4-geo-draws-boundary-inverted), which provided an even simpler test case.  And again, the version that worked in d3 was counterclockwise and failed geojsonlint, while the broken version was clockwise, was inverted in d3, but passed the lint test.

So I guess the basic questions are:

1. What is correct?
2. Is the GeoJSONLint website wrong?

Comment: D3 does not adhere to the geojson spec regarding winding order of geojson. D3 requires reverse winding (coordinates wound like a shapefile). This is awkward when validating your geojson. It is slightly odd that the spec specifies an order when it also mandates Cartesian coordinates, which means there is only one way to fill a polygon regardless of its winding. D3 breaks the spec again by using spherical math, which means winding order matters. It should cause no issues to reversely wind geojson for most practical purposes, turf.js offers a method to wind on the fly if needed.

Comment: @AndrewReid Oh wow, didn't know that. Great advise!

Comment: @AndrewReid - that would indeed explain all the inconsistency.